# How frustrated should I be before I quit, given that I have other options and saving?

Tags: quitting

I've been working at 'startup' for 3.5 years, and I'm starting to get extremely frustrated with the work environment.

There is no process in place for development of features or support. For the last 4 months, we've adding major features to a branch that split off from the development branch a year ago, because people didn't want to risk the possibility of instability on the new version, and have ended up porting those very same features to the older version (besides adding additional features).
They're even illegally using an open source library that's part of the core of the application. We've lost many clients due to management forcing early releases and things being incomplete when deployed.

The  'personal' aspects (flexible hours, friendly relations with most people in the office) are good.

At the moment, I'm in the process of applying for my Masters degree next year, and am likely to get a part time job if I do quit. They're also planning on moving the development team to another country in the next couple of months because of the government incentives there.

How frustrated should I be before I quit? Can this affect my university applications or future career?

Comment: Have you talked about the issues with your colleagues?

Comment: Yes, 2 of the other 3 developers agree with me, the third has manager-type role, and he quite often agrees with me, but does not push the issues with the CXOs. I have tried pushing for more process, but again they seem to agree with me and then forget about when the time comes. We have 5 CXOs and 4 developers.

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696

Comment: @gnat I tried to make the question as helpful to the community as possible without it turning incoherent. But looking more closely at some of the upvoted questions on this site, I can see how this question is off topic. I'm still not sure what I should have asked instead.

Comment: Do you think the university is going to evaluate the software/company that you are currently working for and take that into consideration before accepting you? What have you learned from this experience that has made you a better programmer? If anyone would be convinced on how important high-coding standards are, it would be someone who has experienced what you have.

Comment: "They're even illegally using an open source library that's part of the core of the application" this depends on the exact library's license and the type of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noone but you can answer the first part of your question. How much frustration can you take? Are the good personal aspects enough compensation for the frustration you feel about your work? Putting all that in the balance is entirely up to you.

As for the second part of your question, I wouldn't worry. You seem to have legitimate reasons to quit, so explaining why you left in a future interview shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks ero, sorry if the question was a little off topic, will try harder to ask less subjective questions in the future.

Comment: Referring to the final sentence of this answer, I completely agree. In fact it can work in your favour, if you can provide your reasoning without sounding like you're attacking your former employer (unprofessional) you can make your potential employer feel positively about their own business (assuming they're not ALSO suffering the problems you cite). They'll likely receive it as complimentary "I'm coming here because I have faith you guys will be better than those guys".